# Managing electron child process spawn

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, electron

I have a small electron app and basically what I'm doing is:

1. List item
2. Start electron APP
   Click in start button and this button creates a child process with spawn which runs a jar file. Then a new HTML page is loaded.
3. Click in stop button and kill child process and as consequence jar stops execution.

So the problem is between step 2 and 3. I made some debug and saw that before loading the new html page the jar file is running. But when the new page is loaded the jar file process disappears. Maybe I'm not managing the child process correctly.

Any ideas how could I achieve this or what probably I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you tried to run manually the .jar on your console to see if this runs properly?

Comment: Yes. Jar is running ok

Comment: uhmm, try to run it with a batch file, then you can try to run this file from electron (kinda redundant)

Comment: Hum but I'm not having problems running jar. The problem is when the second html page is loaded, somehow jar process is killed.

Comment: in that case, make it in a render process, create a hiden windows and run in that thread your jar

Comment: Will I be able to start and stop the jar process as I mentioned?

Comment: yeah, can destroy the window or throght ipc send an order to stops to the render process